Salesforce VSCode extension fails to complete SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org
When I do this Trailhead exercise, the "SFDX: Authorize an Org" command works perfectly and I am able to successfully give the login credentials for the Playground using the web browser that pops up.
Problem:
However, when I subsequently try to do the "Right-click on the force-app/main/default folder and select SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org" step,  this dialog continues to display for as many hours as I am willing to wait before clicking on the "Cancel" button.

There is no meaningful error message, so there is absolutely no indication of what the problem might be.
Things I have tried:
I have restarted the computer, but the problem persists.  I have also created a different Playground, but the problem persists in the different Playground.  And I have tried downgrading the version of the Salesforce CLI Integration extension to the version used a couple of months ago, but the problem also still persists.
Version information:
The version information in VSCode > Help > About is:
Version: 1.95.3 (user setup)
Commit: f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813
Date: 2024-11-13T14:50:04.152Z
Electron: 32.2.1
ElectronBuildId: 10427718
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.0
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

The result of running sf version is:
(node:23332) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
@salesforce/cli/2.67.7 win32-x64 node-v22.11.0

The result of running sf plugins --core is:
(node:21808) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
@oclif/plugin-autocomplete 3.2.8 (core)
@oclif/plugin-commands 4.1.8 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 6.2.16 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 3.2.25 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 5.4.15 (core)
@oclif/plugin-search 1.2.14 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 4.6.10 (core)
@oclif/plugin-version 2.2.15 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 3.1.21 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 3.2.17 (core)
apex 3.6.2 (core)
api 1.3.2 (core)
auth 3.6.73 (core)
data 3.11.3 (core)
deploy-retrieve 3.15.11 (core)
info 3.4.18 (core)
limits 3.3.39 (core)
marketplace 1.3.4 (core)
org 5.1.4 (core)
packaging 2.9.0 (core)
schema 3.3.40 (core)
settings 2.4.4 (core)
sobject 1.4.45 (core)
telemetry 3.6.20 (core)
templates 56.3.29 (core)
trust 3.7.41 (core)
user 3.6.2 (core)

Uninstalled JIT Plugins:
community 3.3.2
custom-metadata 3.3.37
dev 2.5.0
devops-center 1.2.26
env 3.0.33
functions 1.23.0
signups 2.6.1
@salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 1.2.1
@salesforce/sfdx-scanner 4.7.0

What specifically do I need to do in order to resolve this problem?

See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249445/error-sfdx-deploy-source-to-org

do you see any related messages in the output panel's various channels? does this extension have its own output channels there? is there a corresponding CLI command you can run like https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/293334/125239 ?
